# nested average over on AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, calculated-columns, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I have this dataset

```
weekday    hour    id    duration
Sunday     1       1     20
Sunday     1       1     30
Sunday     1       2     10
```

I want to have average duration for weekday hour. The step is sum over the weekday, hour, id and then average it over weekday and hour. I want the result like this on the AWS Quicksight or maybe another BI tools

```
weekday  hour  averageDuration
Sunday   1     (20+30+10)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following dataset:

[image]

I then added the following calculated field:

```
avgOver(sum(duration), [hour])/distinct_count(id)
```

to get the following result:

[image]